# Can't add new object to KendoUI grid if filter is applied to any column

Tags: kendo-grid

I use KendoUI grid with popup edit mode. After applying filter to any column it is not possible to add new object correctly. Pressing Add button many times does not show edit popup. But after clearing the filter empty objects are shown in the grid. 
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Instead of standard Add button use toolbar template in which add link "Add" with custom handler triggering grid add. In that handler check if filtering is used on grid and if so store current filtering to a var and remove filtering. Also bind to grid "save"  and  "cancel" events handlers which will apply previous filtering after adding new object (or cancelling).

```
    <kendo:grid-toolbarTemplate>
        <div>
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext" onclick="addItemHandler()">Add</a>
    ...

    var gridFilter;

    function addItemHandler() {
        var table = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");

        gridFilter = table.dataSource.filter();

        if (gridFilter) {
            table.dataSource.filter(null);
        }

        table.addRow();
    }

    function gridSavedHandler(e) {       
        restoreFilter(e.sender);
    }

    function gridEditCanceledHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.sender.cancelChanges();
        restoreFilter(e.sender);
    }

    function restoreFilter(table) {
        if (gridFilter) {
            table.dataSource.filter(gridFilter);
            gridFilter = null;
        }
    }

   $(document).ready(pageInitHandler);

   function pageInitHandler() {
       var table = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
       table.bind("save", gridSavedHandler);
       table.bind("cancel", gridEditCanceledHandler);
   }
```

Workaround is complicated one but really works.