# Bug in Kendo UI Listview?

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

if you open this link https://dojo.telerik.com/EbUrukOT/3 and try to add new record in listview it works just fine, but try adding filter in datasource for example   filter: { field: "ProductName", operator: "eq", value: "chai"}   and then try to add a new record on filtered listview. it throws an error in a console and reload the page. "cannot read property uid of undefined " is this some kind of bug or am I doing something wrong?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding empty row while filtered(nor sorted) is not possible at the moment.

You can remove the filter at the time of adding and re-add the filter dynamically to the dataSource after save.

I found 2 link [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840312/cant-add-new-object-to-kendoui-grid-if-filter-is-applied-to-any-column), [link2](http://aisoftwarellc.com/blog/post/kendo-hacks---clear-filter-while-adding-new-rows-in-a-kendo-grid/2024) similar with your problem Hope it helps :D